# questions on data structure design for vectors?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, tree

While reading some materials on data structure design for sparse vectors,  the authors make some statements as follows.

> A hash table could be used
>    to implement a simple index-to-value mapping. Accessing an index value is slower than with direct array
>    access, but not by much.

Why assessing an index value is slower when using hash table?

Further, the authors state that

> The problem with a hash-backed implementation is that it becomes relatively slow to iterate through
>    all values in order by index.
>     An ordered mapping based on a tree structure or
>    similar can address this problem, since it maintains keys in order. The price of this feature is longer access
>    time.

Why hash-based implementation performs bad when iterating through all values? Does that due the slower operation of assessing an index?

How can a tree structure help this kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing a hash table index is just a bit slower because of the calculation overhead.
In a hash table, if you request item 452345435 it doesn't mean it's in cell 452345435 ... The hash table performs a series of calculation to find the right cell. This is implementation dependent.
**[Hash table Performance analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Performance_analysis)**

Hash tables don't store sorted data. So if you want to get the items in the right order, a sorting algorithm will need to be called.

To solve that, you can use a tree, or any other sorted data structure.
But that will increase the inserting complexity from O(1) (hash table) to O(logn) (insert to a tree, sorted database).
That because each index will be added to both data structures, and the complexity will be O(1) + O(logn) = O(logn)

It will still take only O(1) to retrieve the data, because it's enough to request it from the hash table.

Comment: You don't need to sort the data when retrieving all data from the hashtable in the right order, if you know all possible indexes, which I think is the case OP was talking about. So retrieving all the data can be `O(n)`, but it will be slower than traversing some tree structure (which will be `O(n)` too).

Comment: If you have all the indexes stored in an external database than sure, do whatever you want. I was assuming this is the only database and you want to retrieve the data from that database in the right order.